# blackberry emulator on eclipse j2me

Tags: blackberry, java-me

I configured j2me environment in eclipse . now i want run j2me in blackberry emulator how can i configured the blackberry simulator(i need to develop j2me application for blackberry ) ?

Answer (score 1):

You have to install the [BlackBerry JDE plugin for eclipse](http://na.blackberry.com/eng/developers/javaappdev/devtools.jsp).